# NGINX redirect with query strings getting ignored

Tags: nginx, redirect, query-string

I'm adding around 30 redirects, 90% of them are straight forward URLs, however there's a few that have query strings e.g.

```
.com/?page_id=2966
.com/?page_id=2965
.com/?page_id=2964
```

All the other redirects work fine, however none of these ones work using the following rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/?page_id=2966$ /sustainable-travel? permanent;
rewrite ^/?page_id=2965$ /car-sharing? permanent;
rewrite ^/?page_id=2964$ /eco-driving? permanent;
```

We've reloaded and restarted the server without any luck - Is there something special we should be doing in a config to capture these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything from the `?` and after is the query string and is not part of the normalized URI used in `rewrite` (and other) directives.

Typical solutions are using the `map` directive to [map query string parameters](https://azimut7.com/blog/nginx-redirect-map) to URIs, or not doing this type of redirection at the Nginx level, and using a plugin like [Retour](https://nystudio107.com/plugins/retour)* to handle redirects.

- Disclaimer: I'm the author of Retour.